# Determining the asymptotic complexity in the worst case (O(N)) of a specific function

Tags: c++, asymptotic-complexity

I would like to determine the asymptotic complexity in THE WORST CASE the following function:

```
int j;
float r = 1.0;
for (int i=1; i<(log n); i++){
    j = 1;
    while (j <= i^2){
        r*=2;
        j++;
}
print(r);
```

Comment: That'd be tough since this code won't compile with the unclosed `{` on line 3, and the `log n`. I'd suggest either sticking to some flavor of pseudocode, or 100% real c++ for clarity. Further, what have you tried thus far to determine the time complexity? SO isn't a homework-answering service.

Comment: You'll get a float overflow if n >= 1000

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I'll assume that `i^2` in your code means "`i` raised to the power of 2", rather than "`i` bitwise-XOR 2", as the latter is consistent with C++ syntax, but produces unpredictable results.

Time complexity is given by the sum

[image: ![enter image description here]

We need to evaluate the sums of natural numbers to the power of 2, using info from this webpage: http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/series/sumGeneralPowersNaturalNumbers.htm.

[image]

So the time complexity is

[image]

Comment: yep now i got it, still the 2nd equation is not soo clear, I first thought it is only one equation because i missed the `,`